# How can I send altocoins from a long wallet adress 24-30 characters to a short wallet address that most exchanges have?

Tags: wallet, exchanges

HI I have a  24 to 20 character long adress made for dash coins and Iam noticing all of the exchanges and the newer wallets give me  a shorter adress when I atempt to send from miner gate or from my gui made dash wallet to these short adresses I get an rpc error that the adress doesnt exist please help!
Iam new to this and I haven't been able to find anything about this